# Looking for an EM or QM mechanistic explanation for Rayleigh scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, scattering

The common quick answer I usually see on the internet for questions like 'why is the sky blue' is that shorter wavelength light is scattered to a greater extant than longer wavelengths. The explanations don't go too much further or delve into why the scattering is occurring in the first place. There are similar questions on this forum but they do not quite address all the points I list below.

What I am assuming and what I don't know (if I am mistaken please tell me):

Incoming light has oscillating electric and magnetic field portions. The electric field will induce a force on the electrons in, in this case, the air molecules. This force will perturb the electron probability density distribution which will depend on the polarizability of the molecule. At this point, scattering occurs. I am not sure about exactly how. Do the electrons relax back to ground state distribution and release a photon which interferes with the excitatory light? If this is the case, I am assuming that the light was not "absorbed" by the molecule leading to the promotion of an electron to a higher state because then how could an emitted photon interfere with a photon that is no longer there? Or does the new electron distribution alter the electric field of the molecule which adds to the electric field of the incoming light thereby changing its direction somehow? Or is there some other quantum phenomenon occurring?
As an aside (and again I know this has been asked on this forum but the question has not been answered that I found) why is blue light more easily scattered than red? Is it because the blue light has greater energy so can perturb the electron density distribution of air molecules to a greater degree?

Comment: *The common quick answer I usually see on the internet for questions like 'why is the sky blue' is that shorter wavelength light is scattered to a greater extant than longer wavelengths.* It should be noted that this is not the only reason the sky is blue

Comment: " how could an emitted photon interfere with a photon that is no longer there? "  this is a basic misunderstanding. There is no photon photon interaction , as the probability of two photons interacting is very small. at  these energies/frequencies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics

Comment: Have you read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering ?